# Add number of hours to a stored date

Tags: php, date

I'm storing the current date (otherwise known as the date of the ban) in a table along with the length of the ban in hours (this can be anywhere from 24 hours up to 50000 hours and so on).

I need to add the length of the ban to the date of the ban to give the expiry date, but I'm struggling as to how to come about doing this. I've tried all sorts using the date format and adding to it the number of hours but cannot seem to get my head around this.

Thanks.

Comment: in the table, the number of hours are merely numerical values? or strings like `24 hours`?

Comment: Please provide some more information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your start date of ban is stored in a variable `$startDate` and you're fetching the hours of bans in a variable `$hoursBan` which is numerical value only, then this is how you'll get the expiry date:

```
$expiryDate = strtotime( date("Y-m-d", strtotime($startDate)) . " +" . $hoursBan . " hours");
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I just had to append H:i:s to the date format, but that was probably due to my lack of information in the first place, so for that I apologise. Thank you again!